# How to set a timezone of an E2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, time, timezone

I have a Ubuntu server on Amazon AWS EC2. When I log in there, I see there the following system information:

```
System information as of Mon Apr 11 06:42:30 UTC 2016
```

I am currently in LA, CA - so here's +3 hours from the datetime above.
In the best case, I'd like to have on this server NYC time (because of our client).

How to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Pacific Time is either 7 or 8 hours *behind* UTC, depending on daylight saving time.  It's not +3.  Either way, the best advice is to not change this.  Servers should run on UTC.  Adjust for time zones in the application code.  If you must change the server's time zone, use `America/Los_Angeles` for Pacific time.

Comment: Duplicate question, plus it's a trivial question you can answer using AWS documentation : http://serverfault.com/questions/766256/how-can-i-set-aws-ec2-timezone/766308

Answer (score 1):

With timedatectl

https://askubuntu.com/a/634541

```
timedatectl set-timezone America/Los_Angeles
```

UTC is considered handy when your server communicates with other servers. It ensures they have a common timestamp. If your server is otherwise standalone, you can set it to whatever you want. Most indeed choose one that matches their own timezone, or one of the people who most use it.